# "cannot read property 'ready' of undefined" on calling jsPlumb.ready in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsplumb

I'm creating a page in React JS to implement OCR functionality to map document ocr data key value pairs to their corresponding bounding-box element shown on the document image.
on calling "window.jsPlumb.ready(function () {" in its componentDidMount, it runs perfectly for first time being loaded, but crashes on refreshing the page.

[see error it shows here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAWLb.png)
I've searched for various solutions to overcome this issue but nothing seems to work.

here is my code for creating jsPlumb nodes & connectors

```
setJsPlumbCanvas = (self) => {
window.jsPlumb.ready(function () {


  var offsetCalculators = {
    "RECT":function(el, parentOffset) {

        var x = el[0].getBoundingClientRect().x,
            y = el[0].getBoundingClientRect().y + (el[0].getBoundingClientRect().height / 2);

        return {
          left: x,
          top: y
        };

    }
  };
    
  // custom size calculators for SVG shapes.
  var sizeCalculators = {
    "RECT":function(el) {
        var w = 0,
            h = 0;
        return [ w, h ];
    }
  };

  // store original jsPlumb prototype methods for getOffset and size.
var originalOffset = window.jsPlumbInstance.prototype.getOffset;
var originalSize = window.jsPlumbInstance.prototype.getSize;

window.jsPlumbInstance.prototype.getOffset = function(el) {
    var tn = el.tagName.toUpperCase();
    if (offsetCalculators[tn]) {
      console.log("Condition satisfied");
      return offsetCalculators[tn]($(el), $(el).parent().offset());
    }
    else
      return $(el).offset();
};

window.jsPlumbInstance.prototype.getSize = function(el) {
    var tn = el.tagName.toUpperCase();
    if (sizeCalculators[tn]) {
      return sizeCalculators[tn]($(el));
    }
    else
      return [ $(el).outerWidth(), $(el).outerHeight() ];
};

  //Checked
  var instance = (window.jsp = window.jsPlumb.getInstance({
    // default drag options
      DragOptions: { cursor: "pointer", zIndex: 2000 },
      // the overlays to decorate each connection with.  note that the label overlay uses a function to generate the label text; in this
      // case it returns the 'labelText' member that we set on each connection in the 'init' method below.
      ConnectionOverlays: [
        [
          "Arrow",
          {
            location: 1,
            visible: true,
            width: 11,
            length: 11,
            id: "ARROW",
          },
        ],
        [
          "Label",
          {
            location: 0.1,
            id: "label",
            cssClass: "aLabel",
          },
        ],
      ],
      Container: "canvas",
  }));

  //Checked
  var basicType = {
    connector: "StateMachine",
    paintStyle: { stroke: "red", strokeWidth: 4 },
    hoverPaintStyle: { stroke: "blue" },
    overlays: ["Arrow"],
  };
  instance.registerConnectionType("basic", basicType);

  //Checked
  var connectorPaintStyle = {
      strokeWidth: 4,
      stroke: "red",
      joinstyle: "round",
      outlineStroke: "white",
      outlineWidth: 2,
  },
  connectorHoverStyle = {
    strokeWidth: 3,
    stroke: "#216477",
    outlineWidth: 5,
    outlineStroke: "white",
  },
  endpointHoverStyle = {
    fill: "#216477",
    stroke: "#216477",
  },
  sourceEndpoint = {
    endpoint: "Dot",
    paintStyle: {
      stroke: "transparent",
      fill: "transparent",
      radius: 7,
      strokeWidth: 1,
    },
    isSource: true,
    connector: [
      "Flowchart",
      { stub: [40, 60], gap: 10, cornerRadius: 5, alwaysRespectStubs: true },
    ],
    connectorStyle: connectorPaintStyle,
    hoverPaintStyle: endpointHoverStyle,
    connectorHoverStyle: connectorHoverStyle,
    dragOptions: {},
    overlays: [
      [
        "Label",
        {
          location: [0.5, 1.5],
          label: "",
          cssClass: "endpointSourceLabel",
          visible: true,
        },
      ],
    ],
  },

  //Checked
  // the definition of target endpoints (will appear when the user drags a connection)
  targetEndpoint = {
    endpoint: "Dot",
    paintStyle: { fill: "transparent", radius: 7 },
    hoverPaintStyle: endpointHoverStyle,
    maxConnections: -1,
    dropOptions: { hoverClass: "hover", activeClass: "active" },
    isTarget: true,
    overlays: [
      [
        "Label",
        {
          location: [0.5, -0.5],
          label: "",
          cssClass: "endpointTargetLabel",
          visible: true,
        },
      ],
    ],
  }

  //To draw end points and maintain click event on nodes
  for(let i=0; i<self.state.boundsData.length; i++) {
    //For Left Node end points
    instance.addEndpoint(`rect${(2*i)+1}`, sourceEndpoint, {
        anchor: "RightMiddle",
        uuid: `rect${(2*i)+1}`,
      });
    //For Right Node end points
    instance.addEndpoint(`rect${(2*i)+2}`, sourceEndpoint, {
      anchor: "LeftMiddle",
      uuid: `rect${(2*i)+2}`,
    });
  }

  var leftSourceClickedID = 0;
  var rightSourceClickedID = 0;
  var connection;
  for(let i=0; i<self.state.boundsData.length; i++) {

    //Set click event on Left Nodes
    $(`#source${(2*i)+1}`).click(() => {
      leftSourceClickedID = (2*i)+1;
      self.setState({leftSourceId:(2*i)+1,leftSourceIndex:i})
      console.log("I am left clicked " + leftSourceClickedID);
      if(connection) { 
        instance.deleteConnection(connection);
      }
      connection = instance.connect({ uuids: [`rect${leftSourceClickedID}`, `rect${leftSourceClickedID+1}`] });
    });

    //Set click event on Right Nodes
    $(`#rect${(2*i)+2}`).click(() => {
      rightSourceClickedID = (2*i)+2;

      const items = [...self.state.boundsData];
      const targetItems = [...self.state.invoiceBounds];

      items[self.state.leftSourceIndex].value = targetItems[i].value;
      items[self.state.leftSourceIndex]['new_key'] = targetItems[i].value;

      self.setState({boundsData:items})
      if(connection) { 
        instance.deleteConnection(connection);
      }
      connection = instance.connect({ uuids: [`rect${self.state.leftSourceId}`, `rect${(2*i)+2}`] }); 
    });
  }

  //Handle Left Window Scrolling
  var leftPreviousScrollValue = 0;
  document.getElementById('form_content').addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    var leftScrollValue = document.getElementById("form_content").scrollTop;

    for(let i=0; i<self.state.boundsData.length; i++) {
      console.log("self..")
      var leftElement = document.getElementById(`rect${(2*i)+1}`);
      var leftElementTop = leftElement.offsetTop
      leftElement.style.top = `${leftElementTop + leftPreviousScrollValue - leftScrollValue}px`;
      instance.revalidate(leftElement);
    };
    leftPreviousScrollValue = leftScrollValue
  });

  //Handle Right Window Scrolling
  var rightPreviousScrollValue = 0;
  document.getElementById('image-div').addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    var rightScrollValue = document.getElementById("form_content").scrollTop;

    for(let i=0; i<self.state.boundsData.length; i++) {
      var rightElement = document.getElementById(`rect${(2*i)+2}`);
      if(rightElement){
        var rightElementTop = rightElement.offsetTop
        rightElement.style.top = `${rightElementTop + rightPreviousScrollValue - rightScrollValue}px`;
        instance.revalidate(rightElement);
      }
     
    };

    rightPreviousScrollValue = rightScrollValue
  });

    var mobiletop = $('#rect1').position().top;
    var scrollfactor = 18;

    document.getElementById('image-div').addEventListener("scroll", function() {
      
      var scrollValue = document.getElementById("image-div").scrollTop;
      var element1 = document.getElementById("rect1");
      var imgtop = mobiletop -  ((scrollValue - mobiletop)/scrollfactor);
      instance.revalidate(element1);
    });
  });
```

}

my index.html :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
   integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-
wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/font-awesome.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/font.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jsplumbtoolkit-defaults.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jsplumbtoolkit-demo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./demo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
    <title>Extricator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="./js/jsplumb.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/demo-list.js"></script>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

my package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "extricator",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.9.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
    "@svgr/webpack": "4.3.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.10.0",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.6",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.1.2",
    "camelcase": "^5.3.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.3.0",
    "css-loader": "3.4.2",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.2.1",
    "eslint-loader": "3.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.1",
    "file-loader": "4.3.0",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.11",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "1.0.1",
    "jest-resolve": "24.9.0",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.4.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "lean-validation": "0.0.4",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.9.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.6.4",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-normalize": "8.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
    "react-dev-utils": "^10.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react-intl": "^5.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "redux": "4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "resolve": "1.15.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "3.1.2",
    "semver": "6.3.0",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "2.3.8",
    "ts-pnp": "1.1.6",
    "url-loader": "2.3.0",
    "webpack": "4.42.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "4.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ],
    "watchPlugins": [
      "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
      "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete **node modules** folder and **package-lock.json** file
then run

```
npm install
```

after installation is finished then run

```
npm audit fix
```

then check if it works. if still giving an error run the following command

```
npm install node-sass
```

Now it will run without errors